# Количество "слов" в строке

Tags: java

Как посчитать количество элементов (подстрок, разделяемых пробелами) строки на Java?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под количеством элементов строки? Длину что-ли? Тогда у `String` есть свойство `length`.

Comment: Если строка типа: "1215 544 965", ответ должен быть 3. Не знаю, как еще объяснить.

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения, очень мощный инструмент. Там всё это можно задать как условие в виде одной строки типа `("[\\w\\d]")`.

Answer (score 8):

Если только пробелы разделители, то можно

```
int blockCount = "1215 544 965".split(" ").length;
```

Если пробелов между словами несколько

```
int blockCount = "1215     544      965".split(" +").length;
```

Comment: Учтите, *ровно один* пробел между словами. Несколько пробелов подряд будут создавать в массиве, возвращаемым split() дополнительно **пустые** строки. 

При подходе со split() (и несколькими пробелами-разделителями) придется подсчитывать число слов в цикле.

Comment: Ну паниковать не стоит. Сейчас добавлю в пост

Answer (score 3):

Используйте StringTokenizer и Вашу строку

```
StringTokenizer ins = new StringTokenizer(myString);
int cnt = 0;
while (ins.hasMoreTokens()) cnt++;
```

В cnt будет количество слов (Вы их элементами зовете).

Answer (score 2):

```
StringTokenizer ins = new StringTokenizer("");
BufferedReader inb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

public String nextLine() throws Exception {
    return inb.readLine();
}

public String nextStr() throws Exception {
    while (!ins.hasMoreTokens())
        ins = new StringTokenizer(nextLine());
    return ins.nextToken();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "";
    int count = 0;
    while ((s = nextStr()) != null)
        count++;
    System.out.print(count);
```

}

Comment: У меня изначальное задание было: дано название файла, найти этот файл и посчитать количество в нем элементов. Я ее почти сделал, все находит и читает этот файл как строку. Вопрос: количество элементов сейчас как считать?

Comment: Судя по Вашему комментарию "если строка типа: "1215 544 965", ответ должен быть 3". Вам нужно, грубо говоря, подсчитать количество "слов"? Блоков, разделённых пробелами, если хотите. Метод nextStr() читает очередной "блок". В цикле считаем количество таких блоков. В конце концов это число и есть count.

Comment: @Gonza12 - бесполезная трата времени... Это все равно что метать бисер (сами знаете перед кем). Человек сам не понимает чего ему надо, а вы про токены

Comment: @Barmaley А помочь новичку разобраться с проблемой -- лениво? Ну разумеется, ветеринаров по Африке гонять прикольней.

Comment: @alexlz Да, я бы рад - и постоянно помогаю (моя репутация тому доказательством), но в клинических случаях вынужден просто минусовать

Comment: @Andrey2517, судя по Вашему комментарию

        найти этот файл и посчитать количество в нем элементов

Вы поступаете не совсем логично (очень надеюсь, что **не весь** файл Вы прочли в память). Почему бы не поискать что-то вроде StringTokenizer для чтения из потока ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;

String text = "some text";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\\\s+)?\\\\S+(\\\\s*)?").matcher(text);

while(matcher.find()){
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] word=s.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(word.length);
```