# Нужно создать программу, которая считает количество слов в строке

Tags: java

Дана строка, которая содержит не более 60 английских букв, цифр, знаков препинания, которые образуют слова разделенные одним пробелом. Ответить на вопрос, сколько слов.

Comment: `string.split(" ").length;`

Comment: @Etki если между знаком препинания и словами рядом нет пробела, то криво посчитает (:

Comment: @Suvitruf *сложные задачи пусть без меня решают*

Comment: Числа считаются как слово или нет? В строке "мне 30 лет" - это 2 слова или 3?

Comment: Дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/107220/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] count = "ДАНА СТРОКА".Split.(" ")
```

`count.Length` это и будет количество слов.

Comment: Там же написано: "букв, цифр, знаков препинания". Ваш пример годится только для вашей строки

Comment: Сколько будет слов в строке `"- Доктор,я не ставлю пробелы после запятых,вы мне поможете?\n- Нет! Только эвтаназия!"`, если разделить её по пробелам? Будет ли каждый результат словом с точки зрения человека?

Comment: Так можно потом еще и split к запятой применить.Можно по регулярному выражению.У вас же в вопросе написано "которые образуют слова разделенные одним пробелом" Там не написано что слова могут быть разделены знаками препинания.